# Javascript onlick event in Zabuto Calendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, calendar

I have a Zubuto calendar running nicely here: (example :
http://www.claytonce.co.uk/index-new.asp )

The event data is coming from an 'eventData' variable that is generated from a database. The generated script is here:

```
<script type="application/javascript">

var eventData = [
{"date":"2015-12-09", "badge":false,"title":"School Christmas Lunch", "url":"http://www.claytonce.co.uk/event-detail.asp?id=4"}}
]
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#my-calendar").zabuto_calendar({
      today: true,
      data: eventData,
      weekstartson: 0,
      nav_icon: {
        prev: '<i class="fa fa-chevron-left"></i>',
        next: '<i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>'
      }
    });

  });
</script>
```

I have a 'url' reference in the data, but I would like to create an onclick event on the date to go to that url (not a modal) - is this easily implemented?

I have tried following the examples on the Zabuto GitHub pages, and other onclick events referenced here on StackOverflow, but they seem to refer to modal windows. I just seem to be struggling calling the 'url' reference in my 'eventdata' variable.

I hope someone can help - I'm not very good with Javascript!

thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this function to script :

```
function redirectTODateUrl (id) {
    var date = $("#" + id).data("date");
    for (var i = 0; i < eventData.length; i++) {
       if( eventData[i]["date"] == date){
          url = eventData[i]["url"]
          if(typeof(url) != "undefined"){
            location = url;
          }
       }
   }
}
```

and modify code for calendar :-

```
    $("#my-calendar").zabuto_calendar({
      today: true,
      data: eventData,
      weekstartson: 0,
      nav_icon: {
        prev: '<i class="fa fa-chevron-left"></i>',
        next: '<i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>'
      },
     action: function() { 

    id = this.id;
    redirectTODateUrl (id) ; 

}
    });

  });
```

It will work as per your requirement.

Comment: Absolutely superb! Works perfectly - just how I wanted. Thanks so much!